# Preloading web pages

Tags: web, webbrowser-control, preloader

I want to write a module? an addon? a plugin? an extension? to a web browser, which will preload all web pages by links, which could be found on a "current" web page - a web page on which user is currently on. After, if user want to switch to some other web page by a link  from "current", browser should just open that preloaded page from somewhere, where we store preloaded pages, and do the same actions from new " current ". So, the question is, which of above variants (module? an addon? a plugin? an extension?) could solve my problem, (because as I understand, some of them can have limited functions), or maybe I have to edit the source code of browser, and which browser would you suggest to work with? And if you know any information source, which could help me in understanding how to implement it, I'd be grateful if you post a link! (I'd really appreciate a full answer, because I didn't found much info on the internet about this theme). Thank you!

Comment: do you mean you want to create a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)?

Comment: No, rather a smth built above, or built in a web browser, that allows to turn on/off such a functionality described above. And basicaly, it should stay a web browser.